# Creating a dictionary from csv file with specific keys

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a csv file with details of faculty members.Several members have the same last name.I am trying to create a dictionary with the lastnames as keys and the other details as the values.The data kind of looks as follows:

```
name,degree,title
S.li,phd,Associate Professor of Biostats
d.Chiou,MD, Professor ofABC
F.Li,MPH Professor of DCD
```

I am trying to get a dictionary as follows;

```
mydict={"Li":[[' phd.', 'Associate Professor of Biostats'], ['MPH','Professor of DCD']] 'Chiou': [[' MD', 'Professor of ABC']]}
```

I have used the following code, its not working.

```
reader = csv.reader(open('faculty.csv'))  
mydict = {}  
for rows in reader:  
    k = rows[0]  
    v = rows[1:]  
    mydict[k] = v
print (mydict)
```

I also tried this code:

```
    reader = csv.reader(open('faculty.csv'))
    mydict = {rows[0]:rows[1:] for rows in reader}
    print (mydict)
```

Comment: you can not have the same key multiple times. how do you think to deal with duplicate names? what exactly is your problem, reading a csv, creating a dict from it, other things? what code did you try?

Comment: I want to create a dictionary like like: my_dict={"Li":[[' phd.',
                  'Associate Professor of Biostats'],
                 [' MPH','Professor of DCD']]
          'Chiou': [[' MD',
                       'Professor of ABC']]

Comment: That way one key ( same last names ) can have details one people with same last name

Answer (score 0):

Your `code` and `demo data` has 2 problems:

1. Your last names have different capitalization - hence they are *different* when used as key.
2. Your names are prefixed by surnames - you do not split the surname part from them.

You can adress both things in code. I assume your "last name" is always the last string of the first column after the last dot in it, all things before are surname(s).

---

*Create demo data file with duplicate entry (Li vs Li vs li)*

```
with open("faculty.csv","w") as f:
    f.write("""name,degree,title
S.li,phd,Associate Professor of Biostats
d.Chiou,MD, Professor of ABC
F.Li,MPH, Professor of DCD
K.Li,MPH Professor of XYZ
""")
```

---

*Process csv file into dict*

```
import csv

# process data
mydict = {}

with open('faculty.csv') as r:
    reader = csv.reader(r)  
    # skip header row
    next(reader, None) 
    # process data rows
    for rows in reader:   
        k = rows[0]
        v = rows[1:]  

        # Name has . in it: 
        if '.' in k:
            # all before last . is surname, after last . is lastName
            # we add surnames to the data, use only lastName as key
            lastName = k.split('.')[-1]
            surName = k[:-len(lastName)] # strip key from name part
            v.append(surName)            # add surname-parts to data
        else:
            lastName = k                 # no surnames

        # create/get key in/from dict if needed, prepopulate value with empty list
        key = mydict.setdefault(lastName,[])
        # append data
        key.append(v)

print (mydict)
```

Output (formatted):

```
{'Chiou': [['MD', ' Professor of ABC', 'd.']], 
 'Li':    [['MPH', ' Professor of DCD', 'F.'], ['MPH Professor of XYZ', 'K.']], 
 'li':    [['phd', 'Associate Professor of Biostats', 'S.']]}
```

---

If your data is faulty you can think about fixing names by `.capitalize()` or `.title()` on the key:

```
name = "one naMe"

print(name[0].upper()+name[1:])
print(name.capitalize())
print(name.title())
```

Output:

```
One naMe     # name[0].upper()+name[1:]
One name     # .capitalize()
One Name     # .title()
```